# Parse Cloud Code - Get URL of PFFile

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Ok this should be a relatively simple one. Apologies i am an iOS developer usually trying to understand Javascript.

I have a PFFile that is being saves into a PFObject from iOS.

I now need to send the URL of the image to a web service, which i am trying to do using an afterSave method on Cloud Code.

I have the object being fetched, and i can see the file contained within it. But i can't work out how to access the URL value.

I have tried various approaches, and i'm sure it's me not understanding how to access the value on an object, nested in another object. I've listed what i mostly tried below.

I have everything else working apart from this so help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Gareth

```
var image = request.object.get("userPhoto")

console.log(image);

var imageURL = image.url
var imageURL = image.'url'
var imageURL = image.(url)
var imageURL = image.('url')

console.log(imageURL);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method for accessing the URL of the Parse.File object is:

```
var imageURL = image.url();
```

Per the docs here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files-retrieving